# Select com entity framework em N : M com vários objetos

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tenho as seguintes classes: Cliente, Contato, Telefone, Campanha e CampanhaCliente.

Onde CampanhaCliente, tem uma campanha, tem um Cliente ( que tem uma lista de telefone e uma lista de contato e que pode ter uma lista de telefone).

Consigo dar um Select no CampanhaCliente que busca: Campanha, Cliente, Lista de telefone do Cliente, Lista de Contatos, mas não a lista de Telefone dos Contatos.

```
return banco.CampanhasClientes.Include(x=>x.Cliente).Where(x=>x.Campanha.Id == _campanha.Id).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Eu consegui com o código abaixo, achei que já tinha tentado esta opção, não sei se é a melhor. Se tiver outra forma melhor ...

```
return banco.CampanhasClientes.Include(x=>x.Cliente.Contatos.Select(c=>c.Telefones)).Where(x=>x.Campanha.Id == _campanha.Id).ToList();
```